# npm install, -force flag

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, npm-install

I was installing the packages on a NodeJS backend. Then I run into an error which was the following:

> gyp.js" rebuild
>   gyp ERR! configure error
>   gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "python", you can set the PYT
>   HON env variable.

It said I need some python executable. However when I run:

```
npm i -force
```

Everything installs seems to be working fine.

### Questions:

1. How is `npm i -force` different from a normal `npm i`?
2. Are there any troubles which can arise in future scenarios due to this approach?

Comment: [*The `-f` or `--force` argument will force npm to fetch remote resources even if a local copy exists on disk.*](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install)

Comment: Okay but I am still confused why this would help out with the gyp.js problem

Comment: Your first question was *How is npm i -force different from a normal npm i?*. this is covered in the docs. There's not a lot of point re-iterating this fact in an answer

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Like Liam has mentioned -force "forces" npm to re-download all packages and install them again. The issue that may arise from that is that obviously if you have too many packages it takes more time to download them each time.

For the specific issue regarding gyp.js as far as I know node-gyp downloads some stuff in the $HOME directory and I assume the path in your case has some spaces. Some tools do not handle spaces in paths which is why it cannot find the executable.

Other possible solutions:

- delete the $HOME/.node_gyp folder and run `npm update`
- install the libkrb5-dev package `sudo apt-get install libkrb5-dev`
- install the build-essential package `sudo apt-get install build-essential`

Answer (score 5):

I have found that if you are using a git #branch in a dependency that

```
npm i -f
```

does not work. I have to change back to the default main and back again.

```
"dependencies": {
    "@custom-dependancy/one-framework": "git+ssh://git@github.com/Custom-Dependancy/one-framework.git#mybranch"
```

Comment: for me - changing the branch failed unexpectedly.. removing the dependency - install - and restore - than install again did the trick

Answer (score 0):

Since the Node version 16, "npm i" considers the peer dependencies for all your packages strictly. That means, if a package of yours defines sth. like:

```
"lodash-es": ">=4.17.21"
```

in their package.json, you and all your other packages must obey this rule. Otherwise your app will not build successfully.

But sometimes (during local development) it is still handy to call "npm i --force" and all the packages will be downloaded ignoring those peer dependencies. But you should know, this cannot guarantee that a package will work correctly, if an incompatible version is installed.