# Running npm i on Windows results in EBADPLATFORM Unsupported platform error

Tags: npm, npm-install

Originally, I built my react project on a Mac and later switched to my Windows device. Running `npm i` to get the project set up results in the following error:

```
npm WARN read-shrinkwrap This version of npm is compatible with lockfileVersion@1, but package-lock.json was generated for lockfileVersion@2. I'll try to do my best 
with it!
npm ERR! code EBADPLATFORM
npm ERR! notsup Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.3.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm ERR! notsup Valid OS:    darwin
npm ERR! notsup Valid Arch:  any
npm ERR! notsup Actual OS:   win32
npm ERR! notsup Actual Arch: x64
```

Answer (score 2):

`npm i -f` seems to solve the issue. However, I'm not really sure why this works and was curious if someone knew. This comment https://stackoverflow.com/a/52002179/11031075 mentions that the command re-downloads all the packages.